# Woocommerce in wordpress - Recently sold products?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

im currently trying to get the recently sold products in woocommerce. In the DB-table **woocommerce_order_items** i can see every purchased product, and what `item_order_id` it has as well as what `order_id` it belongs to. If I sort this table descending, i get the recently bought product, but i don't have the `product ID` in this table.

I need to loop out this information from the table, and acquire the product id based on the `order_item_id` to show the products last sold on the site.

Is this possible with a normal loop? Or do i have to use WPDB? The thing is, in the end, you are supposed to be able to sort products by Latest added products, most sold products, and latest sold products. The two first things uses a normal loop, and it would be nice if i could use that aswell for getting the latest sold products.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I can search for products that are sold out but the ordering is where I get stuck. If you order by date its the product creation date not the sold date. It would be a lot easier if WooCommerce just added a bit of meta which had last purchased date or something.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I had a probem pretty similar. I ended up using this:

```
// get order_id's from the past 7 days and loop through them ( thanks to http://club.orbisius.com/howto/woocommerce/list-recently-completed-woocommerce-orders/ )
$after_date    = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days') );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$args['date_query'] = array(
    'after' => $after_date,
    'inclusive' => true
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
    $products = $order->get_items(); // get products in current order

    // loop through products to find matching id's and add qty when matching current id
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {

        // do your stuff as you wish here

    } // end foreach $product

} // end foreach $post
```